# Can I pass state at the time of navigator dispatch method calling in react-native?

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

> I want to pass a state on drawer menu/navigator at the time of dispatch action calling.

```
<Button
title='Filter'
onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your dispatch function and set when your component is mounted using this.props.navigation.setParams

Set dispatch function in your component

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
   dispatch: this.dispatch.bind(this)
})

dispatch(){
 //your code
}
```